# Why does my authorization filter not work?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to create a custom authentication method using `IAuthorizationFilter` in .net core. I followed some instructions so that I ended up with the following code :

```
public class JwtCookieAuthenticate : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public JwtCookieAuthenticate()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CookieAuthorizeAttribute created."); //purely for debugging purposes
        }
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var testCookieValue = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["test"];
            Console.WriteLine($"test cookie value: {testCookieValue}");
            if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("test") || context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["test"] != "yes")
            {
                context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Login", "df", null);
            }
        }
    }
```

what this code basically does is that it checks for a cookie named 'test'; if it exists and has the value yes, the user is allowed through. However, if it doesn't meet those conditions, the user is redirected
the problem I'm facing is that my OnAuthorization method is not being called

I referenced it as a method of authentication in my Startup.cs code like so :

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
            });
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new JwtCookieAuthenticate());
            });
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if(env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

and I added it as a controller level tag in my HomeController like so :

```
    [JwtCookieAuthenticate]
    public class HomeController : Controller
```

however, the OnAuthorizationMethod is not being called, so any suggestions as to where I went wrong, how I can improve my code or how I can fix this issue ?

Comment: It seems that you used authorization instead of authentication. You want to authenticate the user? or want to check the permission of the user?

Comment: both actually. If the jwt is valid, I can understand the user is authenticated; alternatively, by decoding the token, I can check the users permission

Comment: Where are you calling ConfigServices and Config?

Comment: aren't they called automatically at startup ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need inherits from `Attribute` and `IAuthorizationFilter`:

```
public class JwtCookieAuthenticate : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
```

Then, the filter will always be hit before you get into the endpoint, so you need exclude `Login` action from your redirection logic in filter:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value == "The url for your Login action")
        return;
    var testCookieValue = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["test"];
    Console.WriteLine($"test cookie value: {testCookieValue}");
    if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("test") || context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["test"] != "yes")
    {
        context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Login", "df", null);
    }
}
```

BTW, you use the api controller template(`services.AddControllers();`,`endpoints.MapControllers();`), be sure your controller contains `[Route]` attribute. Otherwise, the routing middleware cannot find the route and makes exception:

> InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.

1.If you use the api route template, you need define the attribute like below:

```
[Route("api/[action]")]   //define this 
public class dfController:Controller
{
    //url should be: 'api/Login'
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        //...
    }

}
```

2.If you use MVC route template, no need define `[Route]` attribute, just use the following template, it will find the controller and action:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
//....
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Then the controller should be:

```
public class dfController:Controller
{
    //url should be: 'df/Login'
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```